# How to use image4io on node js

Tags: node.js, promise

Im having problem following the documentation on image4io.

I just tried stuff. So the problem is that the image4io only returns  Promise {}

here is my code

```
module.exports = function(app,db){
        const Image4ioAPI = require('@image4io/image4ionodejssdk');
         app.post('/addImage',(req,res)=>{
            var apiKey = 'api key';
            var apiSecret = 'api secret';
            var api = new Image4ioAPI.Image4ioClient(apiKey, apiSecret);
            let response=api.GetSubscription();
            console.log(response)
        })
      
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: You need to read up on how asyncronous functions work in JS before attempting to work with it. The answers below indicate how you can actually log the response but you'll have problems manipulating that response in general if you're not familiar with JS's asynchronous concepts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns a promise you must use `then` or `catch` to access the response after the promise is fulfilled.

Ideal use case:

```
api.GetSubscription()
.then(response => {
    // Response returns a JSON object, which can be accessed here
}).catch(error => {
    throw error;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `await` a promise to show its result.

```js
module.exports = function(app,db){
        const Image4ioAPI = require('@image4io/image4ionodejssdk');
         app.post('/addImage', async (req,res)=>{
            var apiKey = 'api key';
            var apiSecret = 'api secret';
            var api = new Image4ioAPI.Image4ioClient(apiKey, apiSecret);
            let response= await api.GetSubscription();
            console.log(response)
        })
      
}
```